# file_get_contents funciona en ciertas paginas y en otras no

Tags: php

Saque este codigo para probarlo en una parte mas entendible  (puesto que viene de otras funciones y archivos) y noto que funciona el file_get_contents en ciertas paginas pero no en todas.

Lo que hace es extraer un archivo pdf de la pagina del DOF, para sacar el tipo de cambio dependiendo de cuantos registros no se hayan actualizado, el problema es que la pagina niquiera la lee: https://dof.gob.mx/indicadores_detalle.php?cod_tipo_indicador=158&hfecha=15/02/2023&dfecha=15/02/2023&accionI=imprimir

````
<?php
 ini_set('display_errors', 1);
 ini_set('log_errors', 1);
    $fromD = "15/02/2023";
    $toD = "15/02/2023";
    echo $fromD;
    echo $toD;
    ini_set('default_socket_timeout' , 2);
    $ratediario = array();
    /*$ctxtc = stream_context_create(array('http'=>
        array(
            'timeout' => 10,  //10 Seconds tiempo de carga para el servicio
        )
    ));*/
    $archivo = 'http://dof.gob.mx/indicadores_detalle.php?cod_tipo_indicador=158&hfecha='.$toD.'&dfecha='.$fromD.'&accionI=imprimir';
    echo "<br>";
    echo $archivo;
    echo "<br>";
    $xml = @file_get_contents($archivo);
    echo $xml;
    $moneda=substr($xml,strpos($xml,'<td height="17" width="48%" align="center" class="txt" style="padding: 3px;">'));
    $resdiario = explode('<td height="17" width="48%" align="center" class="txt" style="padding: 3px;">',$moneda);
    
    for ($elem=1;$elem<count($resdiario);$elem++) {
        $ratediario[$elem]['date'] = substr($resdiario[$elem],0,10);
        $ratediario[$elem]['rate'] = substr($resdiario[$elem],strpos($resdiario[$elem],'class="txt">')+12,9);

    }
    var_dump($ratediario);



?> ```

Ya probe con diferentes paginas como wikipedia, la documentacion oficial de php e inclusive la pagina del SAT pero solo con la del DOF no funciona
````

Comment: Es con http**S**. ¿No te sirve mejor la [API del Banco de México](https://www.banxico.org.mx/SieAPIRest/).

Comment: obvio si podria servir pero no creo que quieran modificar el codigo que ya esta hecho, mas quieren que se arregle y que sea el mismo codigo